# Preserving parameter/argument names in compiled Java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, javac

When I compile something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    void myMethod(String name, String options, String query, String comment)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and compile this to a class file, it seems that argument names are lost. That is, when some other Java code references `MyClass` and wants to call or overwrite `myMethod`, my IDE (currently Eclipse) seems to get this method signature from the class-file:

```
void myMethod(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3);
```

I know that Eclipse (and possibly other IDEs too) allows me to provide a link to the source or the Javadoc *(as Bishiboosh pointed out)* of `MyClass` and can take advantage of this. But I'm curious if there is some way to tell `javac` to include the names into the class-file, so that users of that class can see the argument names even if they only have the class file.

### Solution for classes

When I compile a class with `java -g:vars`, the names of parameters are included in the class file. `-g:vars` seems to be equivalent to *Eclipse -> project properties -> Java compiler -> Add variable attributes to generated class files*.

This solution was suggested by several authors, but the answer from Nick finally made me believe.

On my machine, Eclipse sometimes used this info, sometimes it didn't, which was probably my fault or a bug in Eclipse, but not a problem with the class files or the compiler. Anyway, now I know that the information is definitely present.

### But no solution for interfaces

While this works (kind of) fine for classes, it's not working for interfaces.

For me, the logical reason seems to be, that `-g:vars` only provides the names of local variables, which is what the documentation for javac also states. In the body of a method, it's parameters are very similar to local variables, thus they are covered by `-g:vars`. interface methods don't have bodies, so they can't have local variables.

My initial question only asked for classes, because I was not aware that there might be any difference.

### Class file format

As *gid* pointed out, the class file format does not support storage of parameter names. I found a [section in the class file spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#43817) that describes a data structure which should hold the parameter names of methods, but this is definitely not used when compiling interfaces.

When compiling a class, I can't tell if the mentioned data structure is used, or if Eclipse infers the parameter names from the usage of parameters inside the method body. An expert could clarify this, but it's not that relevant I think.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html) about the compiler option `-parameters` is *at least* applicable to Java 8.

Comment: Is there a solution for the interfaces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To preserve names in the class file for debugging purposes try project properties, Java compiler, then "Add variable attributes to generated class files" (See [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-preferences-compiler.htm)).

Compiling the following source:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
    public void test(String foo, String bar) {
        // blah
    }
}
```

Is decompiled into:

```
// Compiled from StackOverflowTest.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class StackOverflowTest {

    // Method descriptor #6 ()V
    // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
    public StackOverflowTest();
        0  aload_0 [this]
        1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [8]
        4  return
        Line numbers:
            [pc: 0, line: 1]
        Local variable table:
            [pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: StackOverflowTest

    // Method descriptor #15 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    // Stack: 0, Locals: 3
    public void test(java.lang.String foo, java.lang.String bar);
        0  return
        Line numbers:
            [pc: 0, line: 4]
        Local variable table:
            [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: this index: 0 type: StackOverflowTest
            [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: foo index: 1 type: java.lang.String
            [pc: 0, pc: 1] local: bar index: 2 type: java.lang.String
}
```

See the parameter names are preserved in the class files.

I would suggest you look into how your source is being compiled, which version it is compiled for etc.

**EDIT:**

Ah, I see this is different for interfaces - they don't seem to have this information available for the debugger which I guess makes sense. I don't think there'll be a way round this, if you just want to see the parameter names when you're editing source you'll need to go the javadoc route as Nagrom_17 suggests (attach the source).

Answer (score 7):

You don't specially need the source to make arg names appear in Eclipse...If you specify the Javadoc, Eclipse will display the args.

Comment: That solution works for me, thanks. Anyway, I'd be interested if it is possible to have information about parameter names stored in the class file.

Comment: No, it's not, and it wouldn't make any sense / have any value in a language that is compiled into bytecode

Comment: The parameter names are preserved in the class file.

Answer (score 5):

It might help to compile with debug support, which stores all names in the .class file.

though I don't know whether Eclipse takes that into account.

Comment: Yes, try project properties, Java compiler, then "Add variable attributes to generated class files". This should preserve the parameter names.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse will pick up the names of arguments if you include debug information in the class file: `javac -g:vars` should be enough.

Comment: I'm currently compiling with source,lines,vars and Eclipse does not see the argument names. I'll double check if there is something wrong with my ant script, maybe the debug level is lost on the way from ant to javac...

Comment: As I added to my question text, -g:vars adds some information for classes, but no information for interfaces. And in both cases, Eclipse does not use this information.

Comment: Please double check that the class file contains debug information. Maybe you've found a bug in Eclipse. I also noticed that Eclipse *sometimes* doesn't pick up argument names but I haven't really bothered to check why.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate Javadoc file you can create 'inline' javadocs in Eclipse using a special comment with two asterisks(*) after the first slash of a multi-line comment.

example code:

```
   public class MyClass
{
 /**
  * documentation of your method
  * 
  * @param name    a String describing the name
  * @param options used to describe current option
  * @param query
  * @param comment
  * @return void
  */
    void myMethod(String name, String options, String query, String comment)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: javadocs are not compiled in the resulting class-files, but you can generate a site with the javadocs.

Comment: Also, there is no need to write `@return void` - I think it even goes against the spec.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support in the class file data structure for storing the parameter names to any method, no matter what javac options you use.

In order to see the original names in an IDE you have to supply them with either the javadoc or the source.

If you have a particular need to get at them at runtime it is possible to add annotations to parameters, but you'll have to create your own as there isn't a standard set to use.

Sorry can't be more helpful

**EDIT**: 
I stand completely corrected...the class file format does clearly have space for named parameters ([JLS 4.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#43817))

What I can't see is how the hell you can get at them using `java.lang.reflect.*`

Comment: I haven't read the class file spec, but from what I can see, this seems to be true.

Comment: it's also the reason given by the groovy for not supporting named parameters

Comment: Just changed my mind. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#43817 seems to describe that data structure as existing. Anyway, my class files do not contain this information, no matter what debug setting I use for javac.

Comment: This isn't true, names can be preserved using the debug flag in javac. You can open the class file up in a decompiler (or use Eclipse's decompiler - just drop it in the editor pane) to see the parameter names are preserved.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confusing (or confused) with classes and interfaces. What you say seems to be true when applied to classes (which I asked for in my initial question) but is not true for interfaces. I've added some information to my question to reflect that.