# Paranamer does not return parameter names

Tags: java, reflection

I am using paranamer.jar to get the parameter names of a method. But it does not get any parameter names.

```
    Class c = Class.forName("com.soa1.MyClass");
    Class[] argTypes = { java.lang.String.class };
    Method method=ABC.class.getMethod("getData",argTypes);
Paranamer paranamer = new CachingParanamer();
    String[] parameterNames = paranamer.lookupParameterNames(method,false);
```

Comment: Is your code compiled with `varnames` on?

Comment: no, How do I do that. Please let me know

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939194/preserving-parameter-argument-names-in-compiled-java-classes), but it will depend on how you are compiling your code; are you using an IDE? are you compiling from the command line?

Comment: I am using eclipse. Are there any settings that I can change?

Comment: To preserve names in the class file for debugging purposes try: "project properties" -> "Java compiler" -> "Add variable attributes to generated class files". But also read @Chris' answer for other possible solutions

Comment: I already have the settings you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Did the parameter names come from *somewhere*? According to ParaNamer's documentation, it uses several ways to obtain parameter names:

1. Via a `__PARANAMER_DATA` field. Obviously, this only works if your class has such a field.
2. Via debug information in your `.class` file. Obviously, this only works if your class was compiled with debugging information.
3. Via a `@Named` annotation. Obviously, this only works if your method parameters contain such an annotation.

If none of these apply to your class, then sorry, parameter names will not be available.

Comment: I am following option 2. But it still does not work. I have the following settings in my eclipse.  "project properties" -> "Java compiler" -> "Add variable attributes to generated class files"

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Paranamer paranamer = new AdaptiveParanamer();
```

Instead this:

```
Paranamer paranamer = new CachingParanamer();
```

If are not working yet, tell me, cause I have trouble with paranamer too - after help of a brazilian friend I've learned how it works. See ya!

Answer (score 0):

keep the debug information when compiling

if you are compiling with eclipse so check the option keep debug information in project-properties-java compiler

if you are compiling with javac add -g option

and in your code use Paranamer paranamer = new AdaptiveParanamer();