# Name for argument type [java.lang.String] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either

Tags: spring, rest, gradle

I am past the Unit test after creating the initial project. I am at Step 2: Building Your First RESTful Web Service.

But test cases come back red. Below is StackTrace code can be downloaded from the tutorial site: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Here is the StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [java.lang.String] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:134)
    at com.yummynoodlebar.rest.controller.ViewOrderIntegrationTest.thatViewOrderUsesHttpNotFound(ViewOrderIntegrationTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [java.lang.String] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.getNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Please add the code which is failing.

Comment: Which test fails? How do you compile your code?

Comment: You will have to download the code from the site http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: Also you may run this on STS (Spring Tool Suite), you will have to create a new Gradle project, you will have to point the folder "2" having the project in folder "complete" you will have to build the mode first while importing the gradle project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems the issue is for this handler

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Order> viewOrder(@PathVariable String id) {
```

since it is the only one that has a `String` parameter type.

[The problem is that you have compiled the code in a way that doesn't include parameter names. You can either compile with the parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939194/preserving-parameter-argument-names-in-compiled-java-classes), or explicitly provide a `@PathVariable` value like so

```java
public ResponseEntity<Order> viewOrder(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because compiler is not able to store method parameter names while generating the class files. you can enable this compiler option in eclipse IDE.
Go to-

Project properties -> Java compiler -> enable/check "Project specific settings"
-> enable/check "Store information about method parameters(usable via reflection)"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35393223)

Comment: This provides an answer, but it is less substantive than the existing Answer.