# Spring boot graphql guide Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-spring-boot

I am trying to run `Springboot` `Graphql` starter project from https://spring.io/guides/gs/graphql-server/. My IDE Gradle compiler shows as Java 16.

I am using Java 17 and Spring Tool Suite IDE.

since it is the sample project from spring website, I dont see any issue in the code. I am not sure if java version 17 has some issues with spring 3.2.1

When I run the server, and post a query.

I am getting an exception like:

```
ExceptionResolversExceptionHandler[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unresolved IllegalArgumentException for executionId 558526c2-e382-1790-634f-ce88818aad13

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not found in class file either.
    at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.ArgumentMethodArgumentResolver.getArgumentName(ArgumentMethodArgumentResolver.java:92) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.ArgumentMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ArgumentMethodArgumentResolver.java:69) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:81) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.DataFetcherHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(DataFetcherHandlerMethod.java:177) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.DataFetcherHandlerMethod.invoke(DataFetcherHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
```

This is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @QueryMapping
    public Book bookById(@Argument String id) {
        return Book.getById(id);
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public Author author(Book book) {
        return Author.getById(book.authorId());
    }
```

```
and my request is like this.
```

```
query bookDetails {
  bookById(id: "book-1") {
    id
    name
    pageCount
    author {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Java 17 and Spring Tool Suite IDE.

My build file looks like this:

````
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
 

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
    targetCompatibility = '17'
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
} ```


Please help me on this one. I have no clue as to what is missing.
````

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this [guide](https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/) to get started in GraphQL + Spring (for my first time) and I got the same problem.

After many workarounds I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797584/name-for-argument-type-java-lang-string-not-available-and-parameter-name-info), and just changing the *@Argument* decorator syntax in the **BookController** it works fine:

Then:

```
@QueryMapping
public Book bookById(@Argument String id) {
    return Book.getById(id);
}
```

Now:

```
@QueryMapping
public Book bookById(@Argument("id") String id) {
    return Book.getById(id);
}
```

It seems a new feature in the most recent Spring version (**3.2.1**)