# Proguard keep all java interfaces

Tags: java, proguard

How to keep all api interfaces and internal ones that are used like callbacks?
I didn't find it there http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The URL already offer the answer.

> A fast but sub-optimal alternative would be simply keeping all interfaces with "-keep interface *".

**Update in 2016/3/25** To keep all methods in the `Interface`.

```
-keep interface * {
  <methods>;
}
```

**Update in 2017/7/24** The class file of Java8 could store metadata for reflection on method parameters, include `Interface`. Proguard v5.3 could keep these metadata with following [options](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/attributes):

> -keepattributes MethodParameters

Comment: I run the testing before I update the answer. It could keep all methods and parameters. If you are talking about the parameter variable names. There is no solution now, because the parameter variable names in not preserving in compilded class too. Please refer [Preserving parameter/argument names in compiled java classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939194/preserving-parameter-argument-names-in-compiled-java-classes)

Comment: //If you are talking about the parameter variable names.
yes
thanks, accept