# Proguard keep interface method paramternames

Tags: java, interface, proguard

I use -keepparameternames but it's not responding to interface.

[image]
The interface's methond parameter is proguard. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Proguard is unable to keep the parameter names for my public interfaces, converting them to 'var1', 'var2', and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving parameter/argument names in compiled java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939194/preserving-parameter-argument-names-in-compiled-java-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proguard can preserve parameter names just fine. Unfortunately, *javac* does not preserve them by default. In order to emit necessary attributes, make sure to compile your code with full debugging info enabled. Java 8 javac does this with `-g` and `-parameters` flags.

See [this blogpost](https://julien.ponge.org/blog/java8-parameter-names-and-jdk-dogfooding/) for some background.