# Preserving argument names in Ant-javac

Tags: java, ant

Short summary of question [Preserving parameter/argument names in compiled java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939194/preserving-parameter-argument-names-in-compiled-java-classes)

> In order to preserve argument names one has to compile the Java source using `javac -g:vars` as compiler options

I do normally compile using Ant javac task. How do I adapt it in order to preserve method argument names?

Current code follows:

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" destdir="build/compiled" deprecation="on" target="1.7" source="1.7" debug="true" verbose="false" classpathref="project.classpath" encoding="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `javac` developers decided to tie it to the `g` switch the `debug` and `debuglevel` attributes should work

```
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="vars" .... />
```

In general you can always use a nested `compilerarg` to pass in arbitrary additional command line arguments. In your case

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" destdir="build/compiled" deprecation="on" target="1.7" source="1.7" debug="true" verbose="false" classpathref="project.classpath" encoding="utf-8">
    <compilerarg value="-g:vars"/>
</javac>
```

should do.

Comment: Sorry, I never accepted the answer because, unfortunately, it never worked to me