# Proguard obfuscationdictionary not working

Tags: proguard, obfuscation

What I'm trying to achieve is to avoid my method paramaters having the names like String paramString or int paramInt. I am trying to use -obfuscationdictionary but it's not working (at least it's not doing what I presume it should, which is use my dictionary words instead of paramString etc)

I have the following Proguard config files in place, but my list of dictionary words are not being used. (I checked that it is finding the dictionary file by renaming the file it looks for, and it didn't compile, stating it couldn't find my dictionary).

```
# ==========================
# ===== GENERIC CONFIG =====
# ==========================
# Logging
-verbose

# Java Runtime
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar

# don't think I use this
# Preserve native methods
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# don't think I use this
# Preserve special enum methods
-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Preserve some source so it can be retraced
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,!LocalVariableTable,!LocalVariableTypeTable

# Specific config
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames # think this is only for unpacking on Windows machines, so shouldn't be applicable
-repackageclasses
#-dontshrink
#-dontoptimize

-obfuscationdictionary proguardDictionary.txt


# ==============================
# ===== APPLICATION CONFIG =====
# ==============================
# Preserve application entry point
#-keep public class MY.MAIN.CLASS.PACKAGE.MyGame {
#    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
#}

# Only obfuscate proprietary code
#-keep class !MY.GAME.PACKAGE.HERE.** { *; }

# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
#
# Starting with version 2.2 of the Android plugin for Gradle, this file is distributed together with
# the plugin and unpacked at build-time. The files in $ANDROID_HOME are no longer maintained and
# will be ignored by new version of the Android plugin for Gradle.

# Optimizations: If you don't want to optimize, use the proguard-android.txt configuration file
# instead of this one, which turns off the optimization flags.
# Adding optimization introduces certain risks, since for example not all optimizations performed by
# ProGuard works on all versions of Dalvik.  The following flags turn off various optimizations
# known to have issues, but the list may not be complete or up to date. (The "arithmetic"
# optimization can be used if you are only targeting Android 2.0 or later.)  Make sure you test
# thoroughly if you go this route.
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Preserve some attributes that may be required for reflection.
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod

#-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
#-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
#-keep public class uk.co.russellwheeler.matcg.android.dfgcvb.ILicensingService
#-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
#-dontnote com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
#-dontnote uk.co.russellwheeler.matcg.android.dfgcvb.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick.
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve annotated Javascript interface methods.
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

# The support libraries contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version. We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontnote android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}





# =========================
# ===== LIBGDX CONFIG =====
# =========================
# Don't warn about necessary libs
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.**
-dontwarn de.matthiasmann.twlthemeeditor.fontgen.**
-dontwarn org.lwjgl.**
-dontwarn org.objectweb.asm.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**

-keepnames class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput*
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {<init>(...);}

# LibGDX | Box2D World
#-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
#   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
#   void    beginContact(long);
#   void    endContact(long);
#   void    preSolve(long, long);
#   void    postSolve(long, long);
#   boolean reportFixture(long);
#   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
#}


-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
   <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class uk.co.russellwheeler.matcg.android.** {
   <init>(...);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}


-keep class javax.activation.* { *; }
-dontwarn javax.activation.**



# Crashlytics 2.+

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, !LocalVariableTable,!LocalVariableTypeTable

# If you are using custom exceptions, add this line so that custom exception types are skipped during obfuscation:
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

# For Fabric to properly de-obfuscate your crash reports, you need to remove this line from your ProGuard config:
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Proguard does not "obfuscate" parameter names in the same way as other names, it just strips them (because unlike field and class names, parameter names are stored in optional debugging symbols). "Parameter names", that you see in decompiler (`paramInt`, `arg0`  etc.), are just made up names, autogenerated by decompiler itself. There is no support for applying obfuscation dictionary to parameter names, — you can either strip them completely or keep them ([provided that your binaries had them in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939194)).

You can try to preserve original parameter names via `-keepattribute LocalVariableTable`, but that might not work unless you `-keep` entire class, — Proguard's handling of local variables in modern classfiles is kinda buggy. If you don't do anything, Proguard will default to removing them.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer already correctly said, ProGuard will not use the obfuscation dictionary for method parameters. Either they are removed or kept with their original names.

In order to keep them, you have to add the following:

```
-keepparameternames
```